# Office 365 Exchange Online permission is not visible for registered application in azure active directory

Tags: azure, outlook, azure-active-directory, office365, imap

I have registered the application in azure active directory but when I want to give this permission **Office 365 Exchange Online** from under **APIs my organization use** tab, it is not visible there. What extra configuration I need to do

I have same account for office 365 but not buy any of its plan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the same issue when I tried adding  **Office 365 Exchange Online**  permissions like below:***

[image]

To resolve the issue, make sure to assign the  **`Azure Active Directory Premium P2 license`**  like below:

[image]

I assigned the licenses like below:

[image]

After assigning the Licenses, I am able to assign  **Office 365 Exchange Online**  API permissions like below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I observe that Microsoft has renamed this License name as well
from `Azure Active Directory Premium P2 license` to `MICROSOFT ENTRA ID P2`