Using Azure Entra Id I cant see `Office 365 Exchange Online` under `APIs my organization uses`
Im using Mailkit to try and read a free MS outlook email account via IMAP.
Now that App Passwords no longer work with outlook apparently we need to use Entra Id.
Im following this Mailkit guide. I created a new free Azure subscription so as to use Entra Id.
During registering an app in Azure with IMAP access or ReadEmail permissions the Office 365 Exchange Online API is not listed under APIs my organization uses nor is it under Microsoft APIs screen
How do I activate this Office 365 Exchange Online API in Application Permissions?
The image below shows all the listings under API's my organisation uses that im able to see

EDIT
The advice is that I need a Microsoft Entra ID P2 licence, now when I try to add this I get the following issue:
The Try/Buy button is greyed out, the message says to Goto M365 Admin Centre to add a licence (see image below). When I do im asked to sign in again but them I get the error You cant sign in here with a personal account, use a work or school account instead but I dont have a work account and when I google this message the advice is to get an admin to create one but I am working solo on this issue and im not part of larger company with an admin.
Do I actually need to create a MS work account to add this licence or is there another way using my MS personal account?

EDIT 2
The P2 licence is a trial and there will be a charge (see images)

Clicking on More Information and we get this screen (see image below)
My desktop app will authenticating users via Entra Id OAuth so they can read their own Outlook email accounts via IMAP but im confused as to how the charging works @Rukmini does not think I will be charged but im not understanding how this pricing model then works??


Are those only Apis present in the Apis in my organisation tab

Search by name type office 365 exchange and search

Yes the screen shot shows all the Api's. I have tried to search too and still cannot see any office 365 Exchange Apis

Search with keyword exchange

Tried exchange keyword - no results. There are twelve Apis underApis my organization uses and you can see them all in the image above. Searching for office 365 exchange online or any combination of those words yields no results.

You need to have Azure Active Directory Premium P2 license

Are you referring to this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78235873/425357 because this link states you don't need the Premium P2 licence https://stackoverflow.com/a/78670410/425357

The link you provided is right I haven't gone through it but to resolve the issue you need licence as the office exchange needs license


Note that: To enable Office 365 Exchange Online API permissions the tenant must have Microsoft Entra ID P2.


After activating the license, you will be able to assign the Office 365 Exchange Online API permissions:


So im coming from using a simple app password to needing a Microsoft Entra ID P2 licence, thanks for the info. But what do I get charged if my app (which is used by 1000's of my customers) needs to read their outlook email account using Entra Id for OAuth instead of app pw?

AFAIK you wont be charged

Thank you for all your help so far, ive hit a problem adding the P2 licence, please see edits

Create a user in the tenant and add global admin role to the user and sign in with the user

Ok thanks for that, ive created a new user and get to the add P2 licence screen but please see EDIT 2

For pricing and licensing please raise a Azure support ticket
